# How to resolve problem that Jest Test Code mockRestore doesn't work

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest for Client Test.
but I have a problem.

when I replace the Class method to mock function and restore mock function,
I use Jest `mockRestore` method.
but it doesn't work.

How can I resolve this problem?

```
console.log(OriginalClass.call);

// it will result is here.
// console.log test/vue/plugins/swaggerClient.spec.js:46
//       [AsyncFunction: call]

OriginalClass.call = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(`test`);
OriginalClass.call.mockRestore();

console.log(OriginalClass.call);

// it will result is here.
// console.log test/vue/plugins/swaggerClient.spec.js:62
//       { [Function: mockConstructor]
//         _isMockFunction: true,
//         getMockImplementation: [Function],
//         mock: [Getter/Setter],
//         mockClear: [Function],
// ↑ I expect this that is [AsyncFunction: call]
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore

> Beware that mockFn.mockRestore only works when the mock was created with jest.spyOn.

So, here is a TypeScript solution.

To translate it into JavaScript, replace `(OriginalClass.call as jest.MockedFunction<typeof OriginalClass.call>)` with `OriginalClass.call` and all references to `ts` with `js`.

`OriginalClass.ts`:

```
export class OriginalClass {
  public static call() {
    return 'real data';
  }

  public static testCall() {
    return this.call();
  }
}
```

Unit test:

`OriginalClass.spec.ts`

```
import { OriginalClass } from './OriginalClass';

describe('OriginalClass', () => {
  it('should mock correctly', () => {
    jest.spyOn(OriginalClass, 'call').mockReturnValue(`test`);
    const actualValue = OriginalClass.testCall();
    expect(actualValue).toBe('test');
    (OriginalClass.call as jest.MockedFunction<typeof OriginalClass.call>).mockRestore();
  });
  it('should restore to original implementation', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(OriginalClass.call)).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/57410473/OriginalClass.spec.ts
  OriginalClass
    ✓ should mock correctly (7ms)
    ✓ should restore to original implementation (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.983s
```

Here is the completed TypeScript demo [here](https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57410473).